# C#: Using a variable inside another method

Tags: c#, variables, methods, tcp, global-variables

I'm coding a TCP socket server in C# and need to record the working directory of the server and use it inside another method. Here's where the directory is set:

```
public ServerMainline()
    {
        string cwd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        Console.WriteLine(cwd);
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50);

            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 50039);
            server.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a new Client...");
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(serviceClient, client);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server mainline: SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            server.Stop(); 
            server.Server.Close(); 
        }
    }
```

And here's where I need to use it again:

```
switch (option)
{
    case "C":
    case "c":
        Console.WriteLine("You have selected option C. Please wait...");
        ServerMainline serverFiles = new ServerMainline();
        string[] files = serverFiles.OptionC(cwd);
        break;
}
```

The switch statement here is incomplete, I just need to be able to use cwd in there.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why can't use reassign the cwd in the case method? `string cwd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`

Comment: Just scope the cwd string as a global variable?

Comment: also you can pass the cws as parameter of a method

Answer (score 0):

There are three option...

1. **reassign the cwd in the case method**

   string cwd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
2. **define cws as a global variable (out of the method)**
3. **you can pass the cws as parameter of a method**

   eg- methodname(string cwd)